# Different sort order from Go and PostgreSQL

Tags: go, psql

SQL query to sort text array

```
SELECT unnest(ARRAY['Go', '[Bravo]', 'Gopher', '[Alpha]', 'Grin', 'Delta']) ORDER BY 1 ASC;
 unnest  
---------
 [Alpha]
 [Bravo]
 Delta
 Go
 Gopher
 Grin
```

GO code to sort array of strings https://play.golang.org/p/UsWAKTz2Zj4

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    s := []string{"Go", "[Bravo]", "Gopher", "[Alpha]", "Grin", "Delta"}
    sort.Strings(s)
    fmt.Println(s) // prints [Delta Go Gopher Grin [Alpha] [Bravo]]
}
```

Why the result is different?

Comment: Might be your collation settings? For example on my machine the postgres output matches that of Go. See: https://imgur.com/a/0Cbeqqx

Comment: `show LC_COLLATE;
 lc_collate
-------------
 en_US.UTF-8` My collate settings are same as yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Go uses "ascii" sorting.

You can achieve that using `collate "C"` in Postgres:

```
SELECT word
from unnest(ARRAY['Go', '[Bravo]', 'Gopher', '[Alpha]', 'Grin', 'Delta']) as t(word) 
ORDER BY word collate "C" ;
```

Comment: Nice! TIL `collate`

Answer (score 1):

In your SQL query you `unnest` the array. This seems to give a sort order without, or disregarding, `[` and `]`.

In go, the square leading bracket is taken to be a part of the string. Both functions appear to sort lexicographically.

Comment: yes. sql seems to ignore '[' ']'. Any reason, why sql does that way

Comment: @MadhuSudhanCS: it doesn't "ignore" them, they are just sorted _before_ the other characters